# How To Fix Scala Generic Function?

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I'm trying to do an exercise from a book (Manning - "Functional Programming in Scala"). Asks to write a generic function which tests if a given array is sorted according to a custom compare predicate. While function for Strings works as expected, Generic compiles, but, tried with: `isSorted(Array("A", "B") lessThan)` fails, producing an error message:

`No implicit view available from T => Ordered[T]`

Functions:

```
def isSorted[A](xs: Array[A], compare: (A, A) => Boolean) (implicit f: A => Ordered[A]): Boolean = {

    def helper[T](ys: Array[T], g: (T, T) => Boolean)(implicit f: T => Ordered[T]): Boolean = {
        if (ys.length == 2) g(ys(0), ys(1))
        else {
            if (! g(ys(0), ys(1))) false
            else
                helper(ys.tail, g)
        }
    }

    if (xs.length == 1) return true
    else{
        helper(xs, compare)
    }
}

def isSortedStr (xs: Array[String], compare: (String, String) => Boolean): Boolean = {

    def helper(ys: Array[String], g: (String, String) => Boolean): Boolean = {
        if (ys.length == 2) g(ys(0), ys(1))
        else {
            if (! g(ys(0), ys(1))) return false
            else
                helper(ys.tail, g)
        }
    }

    if (xs.length == 1) return  true
    else{
        return helper(xs, compare)
    }
}
```

}

Compare functions:

```
def greaterThan[T](x : T, y : T)(implicit f : T => Ordered[T]) = x > y
def lessThan[T]   (x : T, y : T)(implicit f : T => Ordered[T]) = x < y
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `f: A => Ordered[A]` if you are already passing an explicit `compare: (A, A) => Boolean`? You aren't even using `f` anywhere.

Comment: That's not the case (would give the same error), isn't it sugar for subtyping? ```isSorted[A <% Ordered[A]]```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, problem was with supplied compare function, @Andrey Tyukin was righ, btw:

```
val sortGe = (a: String, b: String) => a >= b
def isSorted[A](xs: Array[A], compare: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {

    def helper[T](ys: Array[T], g: (T, T) => Boolean): Boolean = {
        if (ys.length == 2) g(ys(0), ys(1))
        else {
            if (! g(ys(0), ys(1))) false
            else
                helper(ys.tail, g)
        }
    }

    if (xs.length == 1) return true
    else{
        helper(xs, compare)
    }
}
```